# Building icu4c fails due to missing findBasename

Tags: icu, emscripten

I try to cross-compiler *icu4c 51.1* with *Emscripten* (*clang*) via

```
emconfigure source/configure --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=${myprefix} --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-dyload --disable-renaming CXXFLAGS='-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0' CPPFLAGS='-DU_DISABLE_RENAMING=1'
emmake make
emmake make install
```

It compiles most of the sources fine, but fails with

```
Unpacking ../source/data/in/icudt51l.dat and generating out/tmp/icudata.lst (list of data files)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib:../stubdata:../tools/ctestfw:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ../bin/icupkg -d ./out/build/icudt51l --list -x \* ../source/data/in/icudt51l.dat -o out/tmp/icudata.lst
run-detectors: warning: unable to exec /usr/bin/lli-2.8: No such file or directory
run-detectors: warning: unable to exec /usr/bin/lli-2.9: No such file or directory
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'findBasename' which could not be resolved!
make[1]: *** [out/tmp/icudata.lst] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/andreas/.emscripten-libs/sources/icu4c/51.1/data'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2
```

So I am wondering, where it tries to find `findBasename` and what this data compiling is all about.

EDIT:

The error messages come from `icupkg` being built with clang, which does not make sense in this case. How can I specifc that the libraries are built with *clang*, but the tools with another compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it wasn't able to find, I'm guessing, ICU tool utilities lib in ../lib - might try running ldd or equivalent on icupkg